# Verify existing feature state is added in NGRX Store

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

Below I have an example of what I am currently facing in the app:

**app.module.ts**

```js
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [StoreModule.forRoot(reducers)],
  ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**store**

```js
 users: {...}
```

**articles.module.ts**

```js
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [StoreModule.forFeature('articles', reducers)],
  ...
})
export class ArticlesModule {}
```

User navigates to `/articles` and then the `articles` state slice will be added to the store

**store**

```js
 users: {...},
 articles: {...}
```

Now, let's say initially, the store only has `users`, and within a component (belonging to users module), I am using a `selector`, the issue I have is that, I need to know in the selector if the `articles` slice has been added to the store or not, but I cannot use any `articles` selectors since I get this error

> Cannot access 'selectArticles' before initialization....`

Is there a way to ask if the store contains a certain slice loaded?

Comment: You can try `this.store.select(state => state.articles)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed, you can only use the selectors on Store data after the module with `.forFeature` is loaded.

To tackle it, you should load the store earlier, prior to using a selector on it.
A good pattern is to create a separated module for your store and import it from the app.modules

I would suggest you add a app.store module as well. As the code grows, you will have to add more store modules.

new app.store.module:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        StoreModule.forRoot(reducers),
        ...
        ArticleStoreModule
    ],
})
export class AppStoreModule {}
```

new article.store.module:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        StoreModule.forFeature('articles', reducers)),
        ...
    ],
})
export class ArticleStoreModule {}
```

And than import you new `AppStoreModule` into you app.module

Comment: Even though I followed your suggestion, it didn't work completely, not sure why, but having modules within the store was a good call. so I managed to implement this in the project and it was helpful, thank you The Fabio!